# What method to use for this PDE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

So I've got to solve $u_t-u_{xx}=-u^2$ with some initial and boundary conditions. I'm a bit stuck in deciding which method to use to approach this, I don't think using Fourier series would work here? Any hints?

Comment: The equation is from the class of equations known as Kolmogorov-Petrovskii-Piskunov equations, a subclass of reaction-diffusion ones. The easiest thing to do is to to search for the soliton solutions. But I recommend to google the above mentioned names....

Comment: E.g. in this paper http://dergiler.ankara.edu.tr/dergiler/29/1889/19817.pdf people consider exactly the same equation with $\mu=\delta=0$ and $\nu=1$!

Comment: I dont think I've covered enough material to understand the method they are using. I think there must be a simpler way in this specific case as this is meant for an undergraduate?

Comment: The initial and boundary values are $u(0,t)=0$, $u(a,t)=0$ and $u(x,0)=0$ for $0<x<a$ and $0<t<T$ if that makes it any simpler?

Comment: Duplicate question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2534478/can-i-use-separation-of-variables Are you guys colleagues taking the same class?
 If so you could try to work together on this problem!

Comment: Since all your boundary/initial values are zero, there's a very obvious solution, no? If you want to prove this solution is unique, the maximum principle should do the job.