# Can I use separation of variables?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation

I have the PDE $u_t-u_{xx}=-u^2$ with boundary conditions $u(0,t)=0$ , $u(a,t)=0$ and $u(x,0)=0$ for $0<x<a$ and $0<t<T$ I have tried to use separation of variables and Fourier's method but can't get anywhere as I cant get past the part where you make both sides equal to a constant. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Separation of variables with Ansatz  $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ won't work here: your PDE isn't linear. You may need a substitution to get rid of the quadratic term.

Comment: Any suggestions/hints into other approaches?

Comment: Solve the homogeous PDE first? Does this equation correspond to a Real World problem?

Comment: so I could just use regular separation of variables for that, but how would that enable me to solve this?

Comment: Not sure, TBH. But solving non-homogeneous **ODEs** often works like that.

Comment: Duplicate question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2534388/what-method-to-use-for-this-pde Are you guys colleagues taking the same class?
 If so you could try to work together on this problem!

Comment: @Gert If you're talking about solving the LHS as the heat equation, then trying to come up with a particular solution, that method only works for linear equations.

Comment: @Dylan: thought so.